# PHP week cookies gone in few hours

Tags: php, cookies

I have the following html markup for login form:

```
<form name="login" id="login" method="post" action="login_action.php">
    <div id="inp_usr"><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /></div>
    <div id="inp_pass"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /></div>
    <div id="rem_me">
        <input type="hidden" name="remember" value="0" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" value="1" checked />
        <label for="remember" onclick=""></label>
        <span id="rem_me_t">Remember Me</span>
    </div>
    <div id="inp_sub"><input type="submit" id="log_sub" value="Login" /></div>
</form>
```

PHP code i am using for cookies:

```
$checkbox = '';
if (isset($_POST['remember']))
{
    $checkbox = 'remember_me';
}

$year = time() + 1209600;
if($checkbox == 'remember_me')
{
    setcookie('remember_me', $_POST['username'], $year);
} elseif (!$_POST['remember']) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['remember_me'])) {
        $past = time() - 100;
        setcookie(remember_me, gone, $past);
    }
}
```

However while testing my website, i found out that if i am not visiting website for like a few hours, i am getting logged out. I am not really familiar with cookies so i dont know whats the problem in. Any help appreciated

---

UPD: i changed the way i set cookies, but still getting logged out when restart browser:

```
$year = 315360000;
$expiration = time() + $year;
if($checkbox == 'remember_me')
{
    setcookie('remember_me', $_POST['username'], $expiration);
}
```

Comment: Simply writing a cookie with a username isn't going to keep the user logged in. See http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: @Wortex17 alright, so i made cookies set, however expiration date is 21.01.1970, 5:00:44 somewhy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, your if clauses are redundant, making it harder to inspect the workflow, fur us as well as for you.

```php
if (isset($_POST['remember']))
{
    $checkbox = 'remember_me';
}
```

followed by

```php
if($checkbox == 'remember_me')
```

as well as

```php
elseif (!$_POST['remember'])
```

uses both, the actual value in the $_POST array, as well as your custom set $checkbox flag, which is actually set by the $_POST array.

Also, looking at

```html
<input type="hidden" name="remember" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" value="1" checked />
```

why is there a hidden value with the same name as the checkbox? Are you doing anything with JS? I can imagine some value shadowing issues here.

---

Next, once the code is cleaned up a bit, one question arises immediately: Why are you deleting the cookie if the "remember" option is not set?

```php
$do_remember = isset($_POST['remember']);
//Use a timespan of 1 week
$remembering_timespan = time() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60;
if ($do_remember)
{
    setcookie('remember_me', $_POST['username'], $remembering_timespan);
} else {
    //This is where i don't see why you are deleting a cookie
}
```

If you are using this block of code only on the login form processor, there be no reason to log anyone **out**. Instead, you should set a shorter or session cookie.

To create a session cookie (which deletes itself after browser-controlled time/session), just leave out the expire parameter or set it to 0.

---

Netx ou said, the cookie was not there anymore once you revisited the site after a few hours. Did you close/reopen the browser? Have you been logged in in the first place?

My only hint could be that you are using the above block of code on every page, and once you do **not** come from the login page, no $_POST['remember'] is set, leading to the case where you destroy the cookie

Comment: as for the first part, yea, i agree with you, but these parts location in different files so i keep them this way, and i forgot about changing into nice way.

Comment: i use hidden part because with other functionality that includes checkboxes, i couldnt make them work. hidden field returns "0" when actual checkbox is not checked, which i used for some tests, but thanks to you i see it is useless now

Comment: i have also tried just now closing browser and opening again, and i am getting logged out, so you last paragraph seems to be an answer. UPD: after some tests, safari still keeps logging me out after app browser restart :(

Comment: @lolbas does this mean you are able to resolve the issue with taking out the destruction of the cookie at the mentioned line?

Comment: Your update suggests the the cookie is not set correctly in the first place (as long as you really are not destructing it manually somewhere else)
Can you confirm that the cookie is set and it's expiration value is also correct, using the development console once you logged in?

Comment: i deleted code that when `!$_POST['remember_me']`, but as i mentioned in UPD, safari still keeps logging me out after i restart browser

Comment: @lolbas i fear i cannot help you further from my position, unless you can somehow verify what i have asked you before: "that the cookie is set and it's expiration value is also correct, using the development console once you logged in"

Answer (score 2):

You set your cookie time to `-100` then your cookie is deleted if you close your browser.

```
setcookie( "CookieName", "CookieValue", time()+60*60*24*30);
```

thats are 30 days. So you can increase the time.

so set a date in the future that the cookie isn't deleted.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: `-100` is done only when `Remember Me` checkbox is not selected while cookies exist